# How to create a C++ user-defined class so that a std::vector of that class does not include certain members of the class

Tags: c++, class, vector, member

I've created a class that I would like to use in a std::vector of considerable size.  However, within that class are members that won't change for each element in the vector (`cartesian` in the example below).  Is there a way to create my class so when I make a vector of it, all the elements in the vector reference to the same variable? Or, more importantly, a way to not use memory for a member that will be the same throughout the entire vector? I don't want to use static because it will remain so for all instances of the class, and this value may change for each vector.

for example

```
 class foo
 {
 public:
    int x,y,z;
    bool cartesian;
    foo(int _x =0, int _y=0, int _z=0, int _cart = true)
            :x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), cartesian(_cart)
    {
        /* code */
    }
 };


int main(){
    std::vector<foo> vec1;
    vec1.emplace_back(0,0,1);
    vec1.emplace_back(0,0,2);
    vec1[0].cartesian = false;
    cout<< vec1[1].cartesian << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to set cartesian once and have it change for the entire vector (so in this case the 2nd element `cartesian` member would also become false. Even better I'd like to not use the memory to create it for each element in the vector.

Answer (score 3):

No. Just create an associated variable, and pack it together with the vector in a struct.

```
struct SomeFoos
{
    std::vector<foo> theFoos;
    bool cartesian;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: not really. In c++ instances of a single class are identical in their structure. Even if you have a shared reference to a value you want to share, you will gain no benefit in terms of memory usage, unless the value is an object larger than `sizeof(void*)`.

But since you say "I'd like to set cartesian once and have it change for the entire vector" which I read: "set cartesian attribute for the vector":

I suggest that you create a container class that has `vector` as superclass; your class will inherit vector's behaviour, and you can add the shared values in instances of that container class.